# How do i use onHostDestroy() in a react-native android native module to destroy a device listener

Tags: android, react-native, native-module

I bridged a java module to react native that uses the earphone jack to listen for peripheral devices. The module needs to be destroyed after the app is closed or else it throws NullPointerException when the app is opened again. In its original form, the module is used in an activity and hence the activity's onDestroy method is overridden to destroy the object. In the bridged form, however I use it in a class that extends `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`. How do i properly implement onHostDestroy() to destroy this listener when the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Device listeners can be removed by using remove().This.listenerName.remove() should do the work.It depends upon you to use this at the required place.Normally I use it when I navigate from one component to another in react native.

Comment: Am i supposed to do that in java or react native?

Comment: U are supposed to do in react native

Comment: React Native was giving me too many headaches, I ended up just recreating the app in Java. Strangely enough it's easier for me. And much more support and docs. People tend to forget react native is still in beta. I think I will wait till its official release